# Mysterious band at the top of css layout in browsers but not in jsfiddle?

Tags: css

See the jsfiddle here:    http://jsfiddle.net/x7N66/3/

See the screenshot here:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/dC9Gp.png

Note the white band at the top in the chromium screenshot (also visible in opera, not tried ff). That shouldn't be there and I can't work out why!

I cannot work out where this comes from. The dev tools in chromium don't identify it as any part of the layout. It happens after the inclusion of the header_img div. but it shouldn't cause a problem as all padding is set to zero

Note i do have a footer at the bottom which is suspiciously about the same height it seems.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a Reset stylesheet? (http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Comment: If you switch off the "Normalized CSS" checkbox on jsFiddle, you'll see the white bar there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
h1 { margin-top: 0; }
```

My guess is it's a case of [margin collapsing](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins). If an element with top/bottom margins (`h1`s have default margins) is contained within an element with no padding (`#header_img`), the margins will be applied to that container element.